# Pre-measure with continuity from above => measure

Tags: measure-theory

Given a function $\mu:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,1]$ that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu\Bigg(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\Bigg)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$ for a sequence that is  decreasing (i.e $A_1\supset A_2\dots\supset A_n\dots)$ and converging to the empty set, I want to prove that $\mu$ is a full measure!

Here is my attempt:

Given that we have a decreasing sequence, then the sets:

$$X_1 = A_1 - A_2$$
$$X_2 = A_2 - A_3$$
And so on that:
$$X_k = A_k - A_{k+1}$$

I understand that this sequence of $X_k$s are disjoint and that the countable union of those sets is in $\mathcal{A}$, so with that:

$$\mu\Bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty X_k \Bigg) = \mu(A_1 - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n) = \mu(A_1)$$ by the convergence of $A_n$!

Is my proof correct? If not, at least in essence? Or is there a technicality I am missing?

Comment: What you need to do is start with a countable family of disjoint measurable sets $\{X_k\}$ and prove that $\mu(\cup_k X_k)= \sum_k\mu(X_k)$. But, don't you have any additional hypothesis on $\mu$? For example $\mu(X)=1-\mu(X^c)$?

Comment: No your proof is not correct. You need to show mu is countably additive. You have shown something else, not sure what

Comment: @YgorArthur Oh sorry I forgot that $\mu$ is finitely additive, i.e: what you wrote but for a finite family of disjoint measurable sets.

Comment: @Andrew do you have any suggestiins for how would I approach that?

Comment: Show that if $A_n \uparrow A_\infty$, then $\mu(A_n)\to \mu(A_\infty)$. Countable additivity immediately follows